# cmake equivalent to autoconf --program-prefix

Tags: cmake

In most autoconf configure scripts (for example, binutils-gdb) I see configure options like:

```
--program-prefix=PREFIX            prepend PREFIX to installed program names
--program-suffix=SUFFIX            append SUFFIX to installed program names
--program-transform-name=PROGRAM   run sed PROGRAM on installed program names
```

I don't see any equivalent of these options in the [cmake variable documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/manual/cmake-variables.7.html).

Does cmake have a mechanism for this sort of install time transformations, or would manual CMakeLists.txt logic be required to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

If your target is a library, you can use the [`PREFIX` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/PREFIX.html).

```
set_property(TARGET my_target PROPERTY PREFIX "whatever_prefix_you_want")
```

Or you could use the [`OUTPUT_NAME` (or other similar) target propert(y/ies)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html).

---

You also could do a rename with something like:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET my_target POST_BUILD
  COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND};-E;rename;$<TARGET_FILE:my_target>;$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:my_target>/whatever_name_you_want"
  VERBATIM COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
)
```

see docs for [`cmake(1)` "Run a command-line tool"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-E-arg-rename)

The rename could possibly confuse the generated buildsystem if the buildsystem checks an expected location to see if the artifact is built / needs to be re-built. A copy might be safer.